Azure DB Server-Roles and Microsoft Entra Groups
I am facing an strange issue dealing with Server Roles in my Azure DB environment when using a login derived from AAD Group (Microsoft Entra) for low-privileged admin/deployment activities (such as create DBs, deploy changes in it, etc.).
IMPORTANT:
It does work when I am using a simple SQL Login and individual AAD Logins but does not work with AAD Groups.
For example if I add AAD Login (Group) to ##MS_DatabaseConnector## role, I am not able to login to a virtual server and getting the following error:
Login failed for user 'token-identified principal'. (Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)

Script I am using to add user/permissions is very trivial:
CREATE LOGIN [SG-User] FROM  EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE ##MS_DatabaseConnector## ADD MEMBER [SG-User];
GO

Selecting below give me empty result-set when testing:
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER'); 

However, selecting below show me appropriate role membership for a login:
SELECT member.principal_id AS MemberPrincipalID,
    member.name AS MemberPrincipalName,
    roles.principal_id AS RolePrincipalID,
    roles.name AS RolePrincipalName
FROM sys.server_role_members AS server_role_members
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS roles
    ON server_role_members.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS member
    ON server_role_members.member_principal_id = member.principal_id
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins AS sql_logins
    ON server_role_members.member_principal_id = sql_logins.principal_id
WHERE member.principal_id NOT IN (
    -- prevent SQL Logins from interfering with resultset
    SELECT principal_id
    FROM sys.sql_logins AS sql_logins
    WHERE member.principal_id = sql_logins.principal_id
);

I know there is a possibility to use another way to grant access via users in master DB by adding to specific master db roles but I would like to make it work according to Microsoft recommendation where those new Server Roles is the right way to go for such requirements.
Can someone please point me to the right direction if this is a known issue?
So far I have not been able to locate similar issues in the web.

Thanks to a former team-mate who pointed me to the right page which contains the limitation:

With Microsoft Entra logins in public preview for Azure SQL Database
and Azure Synapse Analytics, the following are known limitations:
• Azure SQL Database server roles aren't supported for Microsoft Entra
groups.
Source: Microsoft Entra server principals - group server principal limitations

I am hoping it will get documented again on the server roles page as well.
So we still have to wait until this finally works. As always, it's a matter of prioritization of what gets implemented. Hence, making yourself heard won't hurt, if you have a support contract.
